# Usb ports connecting and disconnecting

Tags: usb, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, usb-3

I know this is not the place to ask about hardware problems and solutions, but I can't search on google anymore... I've been for over 24hours searching on google about my problem and trying to get a solution...

Here it goes... My computer, two weeks ago or so, started doing something really strange. It is making usb's connect/disconnect sound for no reason and my mouse cursor goes to the middle of the screen... I've tried everything... Uninstall usb drivers through device manager, download the latest chipset driver, update my bios, checked the voltage at the ports using a cable without edge connection on one side... I've also ordered a new PSU because mine is 4 years old and may be the cause, but nothing seems to work... The computer makes the sounds even with no USB devices connected...

What can it be?

- Windows malfunction (I've not reformatted my HDD)
- The PSU (maybe it is damaged, since it's 4 years old)
- My Motherboard...

RIG:

- MOBO: Asus P8B75M-LX (Bought 1 year ago)
- CPU: Intel i5 3570k 3.4GHz (Bought 1 year ago)
- RAM: 1x Kingston 8gb DDR3 1600MHz (Bought 1 year ago)
- HDD: 1x WD 1TB 6gb/s (Bought 1 year ago) and 1x Seagate 250GB 5400rpm
- GPU: Asus Nvidia GTX 750 TI 2GB DDR5 OC (Bought last month)
- PSU: 550W no brand (Bought 4 years ago)
- Also have 3 120mm fans

Please help me :S

Thanks.